# Multiple solr errors while starting alfresco 4.2 EE?

Tags: solr, alfresco

I have installed alfresco 4.2 enterprise edition locally & restore some backups from previous builds.

Now after backup restoration, i could not see any error in alfresco.log & share.log but in solr.log, i can see multiple errors. It says tracking filed as well as namespace issue.

I rebuilt the solr indexes but still i am facing this issue. Can anybody help?

```
[org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
16:48:02,714 WARN  [org.apache.solr.handler.component.SpellCheckComponent] No queryConverter defined, using default converter
16:50:30,295 WARN  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker] Tracking communication timed out.
16:50:30,311 WARN  [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker] Tracking communication timed out.
16:51:23,884 ERROR [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker] Tracking failed
org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: A namespace prefix is not     registered for uri http://www.lalit.com/model/customworkflow/1.0
at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.toPrefixString(QName.java:417)
at org.alfresco.opencmis.mapping.CMISMapping.getCmisTypeId(CMISMapping.java:305)
at org.alfresco.opencmis.dictionary.CMISStrictDictionaryService.createTypeDefs(CMISStrictDictionaryService.java:73)
at org.alfresco.opencmis.dictionary.CMISStrictDictionaryService.createDefinitions(CMISStrictDictionaryService.java:48)
at org.alfresco.opencmis.dictionary.CMISAbstractDictionaryService.init(CMISAbstractDictionaryService.java:425)
at org.alfresco.opencmis.dictionary.CMISAbstractDictionaryService.afterDictionaryInit(CMISAbstractDictionaryService.java:484)
at org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoSolrDataModel.afterInitModels(AlfrescoSolrDataModel.java:798)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1935)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1227)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:513)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
16:51:23,885 ERROR [org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker] Tracking failed
......

org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: A namespace prefix is not registered for uri custom.model
at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.toPrefixString(QName.java:417)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.removeMatchingModels(CoreTracker.java:2142)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1966)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1227)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:513)
at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

Comment: Strange, so you didn't change anything to http://www.lalit.com/model/customworkflow/1.0 and to custom.model. If you for example disable your models, what happens.

Comment: Can you actually login into the share?

Comment: Yes i can login into share. I also deployed another custom workflow with custom model & i did not see any error for same.